# How to use IBM VPN with MotionPro from Array Networks

Tags: vpn

I'm trying to use IBM VPN. There are a list of endpoints like:

vpn.dal.softlayer.com
   vpn.dal09.softlayer.com
   vpn.dal10.softlayer.com
   vpn.mon01.softlayer.com
   vpn.sjc.softlayer.com
   vpn.sjc01.softlayer.com
   vpn.sjc03.softlayer.com
   vpn.tor.softlayer.com
   vpn.wdc.softlayer.com
   vpn.wdc01.softlayer.com
   vpn.wdc04.softlayer.com
   vpn.wdc06.softlayer.com

When I try to connect at one from these, the site says it needs to use a software called MotionPro from Array Networks. This software asks for a username and a password. I have both, and I also  have the site to connect. I use the URL of an endpoint, and as a host I use the IP address of the aforesaid URL. Then the software says `not connected, check your internet connection or certificate.` Internet connection is not. Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, the GUI is a little confuse, but I catched the bug. The field "Name site" is a arbitrary name for the connection. But the field "host" must be filled with a endpoint from the VPN, but... when you copy the URL and paste in the field host, you must strip "https://". Without this the VPN connects.